# context switch time of user level process and kernel level process

Tags: operating-system

Suppose time taken to switch between user and kernel mode of execution be `t1` 
while the time taken to switch between two processes be `t2`. Explain which one is true?

(a)`t1>t2`

(b)`t1<t2`

Comment: No ,this is not a homework .Actually i wanted to know the details about this.This is why I post my query in a questionable manner.

Comment: Oh, it's questionable alright:(

Comment: In case of the vanishingly small chance that this is not a homework dump, I have to ask: 'why write your question to look like a multiple-choice homework dump'?  Using keywords ike 'consider, 'explain' 'suppose', with no other effort shown, will get you downvotes.

Comment: I have written such a manner because i am not well in writing english

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is in charge of switching processes.  So, to switch between processes, the time it takes must be AT LEAST (the time to go from userspace of process 1 -> kernel) PLUS (the time to go from kernel -> userspace of process 2).  It'll be more than that, because ther kernel has to do a little work deciding which process to schedule and such...

Therefore, switching processes has to be longer - or (b).